# Can we transfer annotations of a .epub file to Kindle?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, send-to-kindle

I have a .epub file with some annotations and highlights. I was reading this on the Calibre desktop app. I transferred the file to my Kindle using the drag-and-drop service from Amazon. However, the annotations and highlights were not transferred. Is there a way to achieve that?